# I need to write a Python stub to print names of image files and whether they are blurry or not

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

New user here, and just started Python a few days ago!
My question is:

I need to write a Python stub to print names of image files and whether they are blurry or not. They are considered blurry if the value is > 0.3. There are 5 bits of information in each line, the second bit (index 1) is the number in question. In total there are 1868 lines.
Here is a sample of the data:

```
['out04-32-44-03.tif,0.295554,536047.6051,5281850.4252,19.8091\n',  
 'out04-32-44-15.tif,0.337232,536047.2831,5281850.5974,19.8256\n',   
 'out04-32-44-27.tif,0.2984,536046.9611,5281850.7696,19.8420\n',  
 'out04-32-44-39.tif,0.311989,536046.6392,5281850.9418,19.8584\n',  
 'out04-32-44-51.tif,0.346901,536046.3172,5281851.1140,19.8749\n',  
 'out04-32-44-63.tif,0.358519,536045.9953,5281851.2862,19.8913\n',  
 'out04-32-44-75.tif,0.342837,536045.6733,5281851.4584,19.9078\n',  
 'out04-32-44-87.tif,0.32909,536045.3513,5281851.6306,19.9242\n',  
 'out04-32-44-99.tif,0.294824,536045.0294,5281851.8028,19.9406\n']
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: OK, that's nice. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I sure have but don't think it's any good?

Comment: fin_list = []
fin = open('E:\KGG 375 - GIS Advanced\Assignment 2 - Python\TIR043109gpxpos.txt')
for line in fin:
    fin_list.append(line)
    
print fin_list

Comment: metric = fin_list[-4] 
if fin_list [-4] > 0.3:
    print(metric) 
    print len(metric)
    metric = '= blurry'
print '= blurry' , which gave me a result of 61 = blurry

Comment: new here sorry, should have probably included that in question I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have written in the comments. This is for python 2.7

```
fin = open('E:\KGG 375 - GIS Advanced\Assignment 2 - Python\TIR043109gpxpos.txt')

for line in fin: # no need to read these into a list first
  info = line.split(',')
  blurry = float(info[1])
  print info[0],
  if blurry > 0.3:
    print ' is blurry'
  else:
    print ' is not blurry'
```

Explanation:

1. There is no need to read the lines of a file to a list, you can just iterate over a file and it will read line by line
2. To be able to compare against a float, you need to convert the 2nd element (`info[1]`) into a `float`.
3. `print info[0],` will print the filename and the comma will prevent a line break so " is blurry" will print out to the same line. HOX! This is `python2.7` syntax so it will not work with `python 3.x`